# Evaluation of Template Toolkit code samples

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I'd like to be able to check simple Template code samples, so I do the following:

```
perl -we 'use Template; Template->new->process (\"...", {});'
```

But I'm a bit tired of typing this all over again. Is there a "well-known" tool for this?

Comment: It looks like [tpage](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Template-Toolkit/bin/tpage) does exactly this.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thank you, it does. I would like to accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: Well, I did "describe a problem" and "what has been done so far to solve it", and got two excellent, spot on answers, which in no way can be considered "opinionated" or "spam". But unfortunately the most appropriate solution to my particular problem was indeed "a library or a tool".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [`tpage`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Template-Toolkit/bin/tpage), a script included in the `Template::Toolkit` distribution, does this. From the documentation:

> The `tpage` script is a simple wrapper around the Template Toolkit processor. Files specified by name on the command line are processed in turn by the template processor and the resulting output is sent to `STDOUT` and can be redirected accordingly.

You can set global configuration options in a `.tpagerc` file in your home directory. These options will be applied every time `tpage` is run.

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't have -e, but that's not a big deal (plus, I can send a patch).

Comment: `tpage <( echo '[% FOO %]' )`? Or you could use `tt` provided below :)

Answer (score 2):

Save the following as `tt` (or whathever) in your path:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Template;

@ARGV
   or die("usage: $0 {template} [{key}={val} [...]]\n");

my $template = shift;
my %args = %ENV;
for (@ARGS) {
   my ($k, $v) = split(/=/, $_, 2);
   $args{$k} = $v;
}

my $tt = Template->new();
$tt->process (\$template, \%args)
   or die($tt->error);
```

Example,

```
tt '[% FOO %]' FOO=foo
```

Comment: Well, that's what I was going to start out with if tpage wasn't suggested. Thanks anyway, hope this answer is going to help someone.

Comment: You asked to provide a template as a string rather than as a file, which is why I posted this. Very useful for testing little bits of TT. I thought that's why you were passing the template as a string.

Comment: Oh yes. I run tiny code snippets all the time.